# After import of Excel data, big post of form with the values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel, post

I'm currently developing a web application (C#, ASP.NET MVC) which going to let users upload there own data by Excel files to the SQL Server database. In most of the cases the Excel files will have more than 2000 rows with 5 columns.

To archive this a was thinking about the following solution the main key is performance:

1. User uploads a excel file with 2000 rows.
2. The web application returns the rows from the excel file in json, jQuery will do a validation and some calculations on the values, if the values are invalid he will pop-up with some suggestions. At the end jQuery appends the data to a form (10000 textboxes)
3. User can make changes and needs to improve the invalid data, and does a submit
4. The web application uses `SqlBulkCopy` (with the posted data) to a merge table
5. Stored procedure will merge it to the final table

Is this a good solution, are there better approaches? Is it possible to post 10000 textboxes at one time?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you just do it all in VBA?  That way you don't need to redisplay 10000 textboxes that, I'm sure, users won't pay attention to anyways.  If you do it in VBA then you could save the module with code in it as an add-in and distribute that to your users.

Comment: Do mean a desktop application? This isn't the solution because when my  db/excel structure changes i have to distribute it all again to 200 users.

Answer (score 0):

The first part is fine, but the second step is what gets me. That seems not only like it could be a performance nightmare, but it would definitely be a UI nightmare. The solution I would suggest is let the user know which rows have issues and have them fix them in Excel. You then have the option of either adding the rows that were good, saving the file for later use or just discarding it all together. The other steps look good to me as well.

I'm not aware of a limit to how many textboxes can be added to a web page, but like I said, it will be a UI nightmare when there already exists a platform that can make this easy for the user (Excel).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it would be indeed a ui nightmare my plan already was to divide them into: valid, invalid and paginate them. But the main reason i return all the rows, is because i've to do some calculations(on this way i could show a loadbar) on it. Like you said the second step will hit some performance issues what would be the main reason of that? Thanks.

Comment: @SAST I'm not 100% sure about the performance impact, but just dynamically adding that many textboxes seems to me that it would be slow. Today's browsers may get it done right quick though